# How to use my old shrinkwrap.yaml with pnpm 3.0?

Tags: pnpm

We have just migrated `pnpm` from `2.25` to `3.0`

Our project were using `--frozen-shrinkwrap` option to be sure not to have unwanted changes in our dependencies.

Now with pnpm 3.0, there is an option to use `--frozen-lockfile` instead
But if we simply rename our `shrinkwrap.yaml` to `pnpm-lock.yaml`, it says the format is not correct.

Without the `--frozen-lockfile`, some dependencies are in error (and that is the real reason why we want to freeze everything).

Is there a way to use or migrate my old frozen file to the new format ? 
If not, I'm afraid the team will be stuck with `pnpm` 2.25

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no automatic way to migrate the `shrinkwrap.yaml` to `pnpm-lock.yaml`.

I would suggest the following. Locate the dependency versions that are breaking your project and pin the working versions using [pnpm hooks](https://pnpm.js.org/docs/en/hooks.html).

So if you know that foo has a dependency `bar@^2.0.0` and `bar@2.1.0` is breaking your build, you may rewrite the bar in dependencies of foo like this:

**pnpmfile.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  hooks: {
    readPackage
  }
}

function readPackage (pkg, context) {
  if (pkg.dependencies && pkg.dependencies.bar === '^2.1.0') {
    pkg.dependencies.bar = '2.0.0'
  }

  return pkg
}
```

Comment: Thaks for your answer. It is really unfortunate indeed. It is hard to believe they have not think of a way to keep using their own format from one release to the other. The hook you propose would be like rewriting completly our package.json... We don't want to spend time on that. I will push for us to go back to npm which is more consistent within their releases.

Comment: I don't understand what is the issue, to be honest. You freeze your whole dependency graph just because some subsub dependency is broken. If you find the exact issue and pin the version you need, you can update all the rest anytime safely. You could do similar thing with Yarn's resolutions https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/. Pnpm hooks is for the same purpose as Yarn resolutions. npm doesn't have this possibility at the moment.

Comment: I am the main maintainer of pnpm and unlike npm/yarn, pnpm is completely indie, so I have to do hard decisions. I sacrificed implementing the migration but if someone needs it, they can contribute it

Comment: I think there is a difference in our point of view. We don't freeze just because there was a problem. We freeze to be sure there will be no problem in any build. And then,we can decide when we have time and resource to be affected of the upgrade of our dependencies (when this is mandatory).

Comment: For us, it was misleading that the changelog said the file was "renamed" when in fact it was a complete change of format.

Comment: In that case, you could just stick with pnpm v2 and when you'll need an upgrade, switch to pnpm v3.

I created an issue to automatically convert the lockfile: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/1738

If it is not too hard, I'll implement it after finishing v3.1.0